# php - How do I count occurences of items in an array

Tags: php, arrays

take this array:

```
Array ( [#twitterwhites] => 0 [#lufc] => 0 [#FOOTBALL] => 0 [#Liverpool] => 0 [#liverpool] => 0 [#ESPN] => 0 [#LUFC] => 0 [#cafc] => 0 [#cafc] => 0 [#ocra] => 0 [#nra] => 0 [#2nd] => 0 [#secondamendment] => 0 [#SCR] => 0 [#TC500] => 0 [#cpfc] => 0 [#MOT] => 0 )
```

I want to return a result like this:

```
#liverpool = 2

#cafc = 2

#LUFC = 1  

ETC ETC
```

How do I do it?

Comment: How exactly can you have array with the same key appearing twice in it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [**`array_count_values()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function, with a bit of modifications to your array, as it only counts **values**, and not **keys**.

*(As suggested in a comment to your question, anyway, you cannot have the same key several times in an array -- which means your array probably already has your items as values, and not keys)*